# Why my template file is not overwritten by the extension

Tags: magento-1.8

i have an extension that modifies the add to functionality on a product page (add to wishlist, ...). The extension has the following layout xml .

```
<!--produt detail page-->
<catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="product.info.addto">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>shoppinglist/catalog/product/view/addto.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

However, magento renders the addto.html file from mytheme/default/template/catalog/product/view/addto.phtml instead of shoppinglist/catalog/product/view/addto.phtml

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Have you specified the layout file in the module config? Cache?

Comment: romove <!--produt detail page--> this from xml

Comment: i have cache disabled, the layout is specified in the module config because other views are overwritten, but this one is not. After removing the comments it is still not working :(. any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you try this ?

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">
            <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.addto" as="addto" template="shoppinglist/catalog/product/view/addto.phtml"/>
        </block>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

Comment: this was indeed the correct answer, i was missing a part in my xml file

Answer (score 2):

The `layout.xml` files are loaded in the order which the depends in `Module.xml` forces.

Therefore it should work, because the `Mage_*` modules are loaded first.

To debug this, hook into

```
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php:420
foreach ($updateFiles as $file) {
        $filename = $design->getLayoutFilename($file, array(
```

and check wether your file is loaded and in the correct order.

If this is the case, I would hook with xdebug into the `setTemplate` method, set a conditional breakpoint and check for `$this instanceof Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View` but be careful, because there are more than one block of this type, maybe you want better check for `$this->nameInLayout() == ...`

Then you should know what is goind wrong.

Comment: something is confusing me , I don't have a Module.xml file in my entire site? where can i find this

Comment: Oh sorry, you are looking for a file called `<Namespace>_<Module>.xml` normally, living in `app/etc/modules/`

Comment: after figuring out how to set up xdebug i found that my extension loads as one of the last

Comment: the problem was that there was a part missing in my xml file for the extension, however xdebug helped me a lot too , thx

Answer (score 1):

If you are using 3rd party extention then it install template files either on default/default theme or base/default theme. If its in base default theme then it should work. Or if its in default default theme and you are using another theme then you need to copy layout and template directory from default theme directory to your current theme and layout directory. Then clear cache then it will definetly reflect.